# laravel basic auth not working but auth::attempt does

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the default `auth.basic` filter. Database has hashed password and a plaintext email column. `Auth::attempt(array(...))` works fine. However, the basic filter does not.

New Laravel 4 install, ran composer update. Default user model.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S it works on my local vagrant server, but not on Dreamhost. This makes me think it could be the Apache configuration?

Comment: I've run into this same issue on Dreamhost. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it might well be the server configuration but generally, i would say **DON'T use the basic auth in a production environment**, because its as its named "basic". In a screen cast Taylor made where he explained the use, I believe him saying its useful if you want to develop authenticated control panels but don't want to go into creating a log in page just yet.

That said, I think you should use a more conventional HTML log in page, and if you really want basic auth, you should manually set that up using a `.htpasswd` file.

Comment: I'm only using it to secure a directory on my development server. It will be fully integrated when it is ready for deployment. But I dont understand why it would work locally but not on my server.

Comment: I can't answer that but since it's a feature meant for development I wouldn't give it too much thought.

Comment: @Jamie Have you tried checking directory permissions? Because quite possible some permissions may cause this behaviour.